# Xamarin Studio: Does not display The Android Template

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-ndk, xamarin.android

Am new to Xamarin Studio and am trying to set it up for my mobile development, and the problem is that the android template is not showing. I have set up the NDK, the SDK and i have also installed Java as the log show below in the picture but what i do not understand is why it is saying **Did not find Xamarin.Android** and **Found Android SDK. API levels: (none)** i have installed API 23 and 19.

Please help me solve this problem. thanks in advance

[Xamarin Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D75Aw.png)

Comment: Your screenshot shows a Windows installation so you want to use Xamarin Studio on a Windows PC?

Comment: yes for windows

Comment: Xamarin Studio for Windows support is discontinued. I would recommend you to install Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.